# how to hide objective-c delegate method comments out of header file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, comments, header-files

currently, I am developing a library, there are some delegate methods need to be commented, but I don't want it to be seen in the header file, because it may be changed by others and it is too much for the header file. How can I achieve this?
[this is cocoa touch delegate method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5emY.png)

[this is where it is declared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeRfA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do by it using categories.. Create a separator header file (Private Header) with any post fix like `*_Internal.h`. And define all the private methods / delegates there.

**Example**

**Hello.h**

```
@interface Hello : NSObject
- (void)publicMethod;
@end
```

**Hello_Internal.h**

```
@interface Hello (Internal)
- (void)privateMethod;
@end
```

**Hello.m**

```
@implementation Hello
- (void)privateMethod {

}
- (void)publicMethod {

}
@end
```

**Use within the library**

```
#import "Hello.h"
#import "Hello_Internal.h"
```